# Common column header in display table Struts2

Tags: jsp, displaytag

```
   ___________________________________________________________________
  |___________ ABCDEFGH__________    | ____________  XYZWGHI__________|
  |___1__________|_____2_____________|_______3_________|_____4________|
  |00000000000000|00000 11111 2222   |    JT 60 R2    |   0.00000000  |
  |11111111111111|PLAST WHITE MFPE   |    JT 60 R3    |   0.00000000  |
  |22222222222222|PLAST WHITE MFPE   |    0681 R3     |   0.00000000  |
  |______________|___________________|________________|_______________|
```

I am using display table in my application to create tables in JSP. Now my requirement is to create common column headers like below. I really dont have any clue.
Not looking for exact solution, but any guidance will be of great help...

Comment: can you explain a bit more of what you mean - do you want the column names to be called something dynamically?

Comment: no. Its not dynamic. It should be static. But i am not able to figure  out that how can i create a common header for 2 columns 1 and 2 as well as 3 and 4.

Comment: Why not create it in plain HTML ?

Comment: good option...but how?